# Draw path with text in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create a path with some text like this:

[image]

I have tried

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (3,1) -- (5,1) -- (6,2) -- (8,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

but I don't know how to place text at the appropriate places.

I can also draw the red line with the text at the right with

```
\draw [red] (0,0) -- (8,0) node [above, near end] {text};
```

Comment: `\draw (0,0) -- node [above, pos=0.3] {text} (2,0) -- (3,1) -- node [above, pos=0.3] {text} (5,1) -- (6,2) -- node [above, pos=0.3] {text} (8,2);` doesn't work?

Comment: But I also want the line to be curved in the steps

Comment: Use `controls` instead of straight lines.

Comment: I have tried `\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) .. controls (4,0) and (4.5,0.5) .. (5,1) -- (9,1);` but it produces the exact same as `\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (5,1) -- (9,1);`

Comment: To obtain the curved lines you could split the path (using 6 nodes) and add the option `[out=0,in=180]` where you want the curve. This may be a little cumbersome, since you have to define all the nodes required, but it works fine, and you can easily modify it.